# Where does PyCharm store the Python Interpreters?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, portable-applications

I would like to put PyCharm and WinPython under version control and
store the relative path to the python interpreter in the PyCharm settings.

=>What PyCharm configuration file do I need to adapt to store the path to my Python Interpreter?

Is it included in one of following directories?

```
-Didea.properties.file="%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\bin\idea.properties" 
-Didea.config.path="%PAL:DataDir%\config" 
-Didea.system.path="%PAL:DataDir%\system" 
-Didea.plugins.path="%PAL:DataDir%\config\plugins" 
-Didea.log.path="%PAL:DataDir%\system\log"
```

[image]

My current configuration for a portable app (based on https://portableapps.com/node/56602):

PyCharmPortable.ini

```
[Launch]
ProgramExecutable=\PyCharm\jbr\bin\javaw.exe
CommandLineArguments=-Djb.vmOptionsFile="%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\bin\pycharm64.exe.vmoptions" -XX:ErrorFile="%PAL:DataDir%\java_error_in_pycharm.log" -XX:HeapDumpPath="%PAL:DataDir%\java_error_in_pycharm.hprof" -Didea.properties.file="%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\bin\idea.properties" -Didea.config.path="%PAL:DataDir%\config" -Didea.system.path="%PAL:DataDir%\system" -Didea.plugins.path="%PAL:DataDir%\config\plugins" -Didea.log.path="%PAL:DataDir%\system\log" -Didea.platform.prefix=PyCharmCore -cp "%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\lib\bootstrap.jar;%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\lib\util.jar;%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\lib\jdom.jar;%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\lib\log4j.jar;%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\lib\jna.jar" com.intellij.idea.Main
WorkingDirectory=%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm
DirectoryMoveOK=yes
SupportsUNC=yes

[Activate]
Registry=false
XML=true

[Environment]
JAVA_HOME=%PAL:AppDir%\PyCharm\jbr
PYTHON=%PAL:AppDir%\WinPython\python-3.9.4.amd64\python.exe
PYTHON_PATH=%PAL:AppDir%\WinPython\python-3.9.4.amd64;%PAL:AppDir%\WinPython\python-3.9.4.amd64\Scripts;%PAL:AppDir%\WinPython\python-3.9.4\Lib
VEUSZ=%PAL:AppDir%\Veusz
CPLEX=%PAL:AppDir%\cplex\bin\x64_win64
WINGLPK=%PAL:AppDir%\WinGlpk\w64
GUROBI=%PAL:AppDir%\gurobi\win64
PATH=%PYTHON_PATH%;%VEUSZ%;%CPLEX%;%WINGLPK%;%GUROBI%;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is under

[idea.config.path](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) => options => file "jdk.table.xml" => "homePath"

```
<application>
  <component name="ProjectJdkTable">
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Python 3.9" />
      <type value="Python SDK" />
      <version value="Python 3.9.4" />
      <homePath value="C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.9.4.amd64\python.exe" />
...
```

Furthermore, PyCharm supports the variable `$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$`:

```
 <homePath value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$\..\WinPython\python-3.9.4.amd64\python.exe" />
```

---

`idea.config.path` sample at ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2