# PyCharm "Interpreter Paths" -- What are they and where are they stored?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, pythonpath

I have a PyCharm project, named `pycharm_projects`. In it, I create a virtualenv Python interpreter, `example_virtualenv`. Then I click Interpreters -> Show all -> example_virtualenv -> Show interpreter paths -> Add path. I add `S:\example_python_folder`, making the list of paths look like the following:

```
C:\Python37\DLLs
C:\Python37\Lib
C:\Python37
S:\example_pycharm
S:\example_pycharm\Lib\site-packages
S:\example_python_folder  (added by user)
```

Suppose I want to give this configuration to another user without sending them my entire PyCharm project configuration. Is there a way to export from one machine and import to another?

I've searched all of `pycharm_projects/.idea` and `example_pycharm/`. To my knowledge, neither contains the string `example_python_folder`, and the only reference to `example_virtualenv` is here:

`.idea/pycharm_projects.iml` contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Python 3.7 (example_virtualenv)" jdkType="Python SDK" />
    ... <snip> ...
  </component>
</module>
```

But no reference to the path or any configuration. Where is this configuration information stored?

(For completeness, the [JetBrains docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html) explain that they are added to PYTHONPATH and used for resolving modules, but not how they are saved.)

Comment: This is not an answer because I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for, but you can extract your settings as a `.zip` to any given folder and then search for your project in that `.zip`. Chances are you will find what you want, and to make a wild guess I think the file you want is named `jdk.table.xml`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182223/where-does-pycharm-store-the-python-interpreters

Comment: If it's an IDE-wide interpreter, then you should look in the IDE-wide settings. Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory for the folder location for your OS.